# React leaflet does not show anything

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, leaflet

I tried for many hours but nothing shows up on the following code...

Does anyone know what the failure is?

```js
// material-ui
import { TileLayer, MapContainer } from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

// ==============================|| SAMPLE PAGE ||============================== //

const Dashboard_5G = () => {
    return (
        
        <MapContainer Center={[0, 0]} zoom={4} style={{height: '100%'}}>
            <TileLayer
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
        </MapContainer>
    )
    };

export default Dashboard_5G;
```

This is what It displays
[image]

Comment: `height: 100vh?` and center with c not C

Comment: that was the solution. Thanks.